# Doesn't Dependency Injection simply move the issue elsewhere?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

So Dependency Injection is recommended usually to help with unit testing, to solve the problem of having a class dependent on other classes. This sounds great, but let me walk through the issue I'm facing.

Here is a regular implementation without DI:

```
class Upper{
    Middle middle = new Middle();
}

class Middle{
    Lower lower = new Lower();
}

class Lower{
}
```

Now let's start at the bottom. Middle depends on Lower, we don't really want that, so we'll create a redundant interface for Lower and pass that to the constructor of Middle instead:

```
class Middle{
    Lower lower;
    public Middle(ILower lower){
        this.lower = lower;
    }
}

interface ILower{
}

class Lower : ILower{
}
```

Well this sounds great, right? Well not really. Most examples I've seen stop here, forgetting that something needs to use the class Middle. Now we have to update Upper to be compatible:

```
class Upper{
    Middle middle = new Middle(new Lower());
}
```

This doesn't seem very useful... All that we've done is moved the problem up a level, and created an unusual dependency: Upper depends on Lower now? That's definitely not an improvement.

I must be missing the benefit, but it seems like DI just moved the issue rather than solved it. In fact, it also makes the code harder to understand.

Also, here is a "full" implementation:

```
interface IUpper {
}

class Upper : IUpper {
    Middle middle;
    public Upper(IMiddle middle){
        this.middle = middle;
    }
}

interface IMiddle {
}

class Middle : IMiddle {
    Lower lower;
    public Middle(ILower lower){
        this.lower = lower;
    }
}

interface ILower {
}

class Lower : ILower {
}
```

But again, I'm just moving the problem. To use Upper, I need:

```
new Upper(new Middle(new Lower()));
```

and now I depend on 3 classes!

Comment: Key point is with dependency injection you don't construct objects yourself -dependency injection container does that. So in your last example, to get `Upper` you do something like `container.GetService<Upper>`, not `new Upper(new Middle(new Lower()))`

Comment: This is not dependency injection, this is just creating and passing instantiated objects into a constructor

Comment: I think you should continue reading/watching that tutorial about DI up to point where it will reach out DI Containers, then you'll understand the point.

Comment: Yes, you are moving the problem. You're however not only _moving_ the problem, you are _centralizing_ it. We call this centralized place, the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). The advantages of Dependency Injection (DI) go above and beyond the benefit of testing. There's a [great book](https://manning.com/seemann/) about DI that will completely answer your question (and many more) in a very satisfactory way. There’s a [second edition](https://manning.com/seemann2/) of this book coming out (that I'm coauthoring).

Comment: The comments that Evk and MichaelRandall left are talking about using *dependency injection containers*, which are optional when referring to the *dependency injection pattern*. Please read the book in @Steven's answer. Because dependency injection is a frequently misunderstood topic, the Internet is fraught with misleading information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection simply refers to the way you create classes, so that their dependencies are provided for them ("injected" into them) instead of classes creating instances of their own dependencies.

**Does DI just move the problem of creating class instances somewhere else?**

**Yes, that's exactly what it does, and that's good.**

Every class instance that you use has to be instantiated somewhere. The question is where that instantiation takes place, and whether it makes your classes more or less manageable and testable.

The trade-off is that if one class directly creates instances of other classes it depends on, then sure, calling the constructor for that outer class is much simpler. You create that class, and it creates a bunch of other classes, and they create more classes, and so on. But each class that directly creates other classes becomes harder and harder to unit test. You can't write a test for just the behavior of one class when that behavior includes the behavior of the classes it creates, the classes they create, and so on. So in return for simpler constructor calls, you get code which is just about impossible to test and also very difficult to maintain.

Dependency injection moves creation of a class's dependencies out of the class. That makes *each individual class* easier to test and maintain, but it creates a different problem, as you've observed. Now your constructor calls are much more complicated, creating all sorts of nested dependencies.

What solves that problem is a dependency injection container, also called an IoC container. Some examples are Windsor, Autofac, Unity, and there are many more. With these, you simply specify an implementation for each individual interface on which any class might depend.

For example (this is Windsor syntax, but they're all somewhat similar)

```
container.Register(Component.For<InterfaceA, ImplementationToUse>());
container.Register(Component.For<InterfaceB, ImplementationForThis>());
container.Register(Component.For<InterfaceC, ImplementationToUse>());
```

Then, if you call

```
var thingINeed = container.Resolve<InterfaceA>();
```

(That's not actually how we get a class instance from a container, but that's another story.)

It's going to figure out which classes it needs to create to pass the the constructor of the implementation. If those classes have more dependencies, it will create those, and so on, and so on.

So now you've got the best of both worlds. You can create as many small, testable classes as you want, with tons of nested dependencies, all depending on abstractions. If you were to try to call their constructors directly it would be insanely complicated, way beyond the example in your question. But you don't have to do that. You can just think of each class individually - what does it do, and what interfaces does it *directly* depend on?

You still have some complexity. Instead of calling a bunch of constructors you now have to register individual dependencies with a container. But it's a good trade-off, and you come out ahead because your classes are decoupled and testable.

Comment: While this might make the code nicer, I'm still not convinced we've accomplished much. Now you just have a dependency on the container. Should I be injecting the container as well? If so, we're just back to the same problem I originally stated.

Comment: The key - and this is going to sound totally wrong - is to avoid having your classes depend on the container. The container is set up in the "composition root" which is like the startup of your application. But how that is done varies from one type of app to the next. It's built into ASP.NET Core. It's getting the container to create your MVC controllers and WCF service instances or whatever else is the entry point, and then it constructs the dependencies for those classes, and their dependencies, and so on. So the next step would be to determine what sort of app you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

When you inject dependencies, you are not exempt from the need to instantiate classes. You take the creation of dependencies out of dependent classes so that they do not depend on their specific implementation (calling the constructor of the aggregated class).
Yes, putting dependencies on the upper level, you get this line:

```cs
new Upper(new Middle(new Lower()));
```

To create an object, you need to resolve the tree of its dependencies. To facilitate this work, there are many [IoC containers](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx). They allow you to reduce the recording to this:

```cs
var upper = iocContainer.resolve<IUpperInterface>();
```

As advantages, you get class testability, flexibility and re-useability.